# Exception Container-launch

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

Hi I have installed Cloudera Manager.While turning my benchmarking tests map-reduce task is failing saying following error message :

```
   16/04/01 12:42:40 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1459494626924_0001 running in uber mode : false
16/04/01 12:42:40 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/04/01 12:42:54 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 16% reduce 0%
16/04/01 12:42:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 29% reduce 0%
16/04/01 12:42:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 75% reduce 0%
16/04/01 12:42:57 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 83% reduce 0%
16/04/01 12:42:59 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/04/01 12:43:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1459494626924_0001_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1459494626924_0001_01_000010
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:561)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:478)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:738)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

16/04/01 12:43:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1459494626924_0001_r_000005_0, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1459494626924_0001_01_000015
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:561)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:478)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:738)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

16/04/01 12:43:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1459494626924_0001_r_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1459494626924_0001_01_000011
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:561)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:478)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:738)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

16/04/01 12:43:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1459494626924_0001_r_000006_0, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1459494626924_0001_01_000016
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:561)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:478)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:738)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

16/04/01 12:43:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1459494626924_0001_r_000004_0, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1459494626924_0001_01_000014
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:561)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:478)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:738)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

what could be the issue that need to be check.I have done YARN tuning using excel sheet provided by cloudera.I also tried to adjust Namenode's Vcores and memory.

In log file I can see following error message

```
  2016-03-30 22:04:27,404 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=yarn     IP=10.195.48.127        OPERATION=refreshNodes  TARGET=AdminService     RESULT=SUCCESS
2016-03-30 17:38:24,133 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2016-03-30 17:38:24,148 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
2016-03-30 17:38:24,151 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@slave5:8088
2016-03-30 17:38:24,151 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
2016-03-30 17:38:24,152 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
2016-03-30 17:38:24,254 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 8032
2016-03-30 17:38:24,257 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 8032
2016-03-30 17:38:24,257 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2016-03-30 17:38:24,257 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 8033
2016-03-30 17:38:24,260 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 8033
2016-03-30 17:38:24,260 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2016-03-30 17:38:24,263 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Error in handling event type STATUS_UPDATE for node slave2:8041
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher$GenericEventHandler.handle(AsyncDispatcher.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl$StatusUpdateWhenHealthyTransition.transition(RMNodeImpl.java:778)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl$StatusUpdateWhenHealthyTransition.transition(RMNodeImpl.java:736)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl.handle(RMNodeImpl.java:418)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl.handle(RMNodeImpl.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$NodeEventDispatcher.handle(ResourceManager.java:866)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$NodeEventDispatcher.handle(ResourceManager.java:850)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1219)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:340)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.put(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:338)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher$GenericEventHandler.handle(AsyncDispatcher.java:242)
        ... 13 more
2016-03-30 17:38:24,283 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioning to standby state
2016-03-30 17:38:24,283 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping ResourceManager metrics system...
2016-03-30 17:38:24,284 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: ResourceManager metrics system stopped.
2016-03-30 17:38:24,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: ResourceManager metrics system shutdown complete.
2016-03-30 17:38:24,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: AsyncDispatcher is draining to stop, igonring any new events.
```

Could anybody suggest what is the problem ??

Comment: I got the solution..Its all about heap memory size. :)

Comment: Please provide exact files to edit . Thanks in advance